# At what point would US government lose control over its national debt?

Tags: united-states, debt

[image]

[image]

From [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_debt_of_the_United_States) we can clearly see that US national debt is growing steadily after 2010 and now it's larger than US GDP already (at the end of 2019).

Still it's commonly believed the debt is maintainable. At least, neither the Obama administration nor the Trump administration care to spend (enough) effort to eliminate the debt.

I wonder, at what point (or at what debt/GDP ratio) would the US government truly lose control over the debt?

Comment: welcome to Politics.SE. Can you please narrow down the scope of your post? There are a lot of questions that are hard to cover in a single answer here. Typically we prefer posts with a single clear question that can be answered.

Comment: @Alexei rephrased.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that taxation and budgeting is the prerogative of Congress. The President has some discretion in how to spend the money received from congress, but how much to spent is the decision of congress. So making the administrations responsible for the state deficit puts the blame on the wrong people.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, but the president also proposes the initial budget and signs off on the adopted budget, so it's not like any administration has no responsibility for its deficits.

Comment: @jeffronicus: somewhat related question...  https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49961/do-bipartisan-cohabitation-budgets-widen-the-deficit-more-than-one-party-budgets Reagarding this question... a way to make it more objective is to (1) ask about a comparison with other countries, e.g. on debt/GDP ratio; (2) ask why some argue the US can even exceed such benchmarks.

Comment: To be honest, I think this is a question for the economics SE.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it would require some event where the trust in America failed.

The Debt/Inflation in the US isn't terrible, and US can also today print money without inflation because the trust in the country is enormous.

With the exception of a few countries that due to political reasons convert their USD to Gold then everybody is confident in having money in USD.

Comment: Not the "print money" argument pls https://www.cnbc.com/2018/09/11/trump-once-considered-just-printing-money-to-lower-the-national-debt-woodward-reports.html https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/why-government-cannot-print-money-to-pay-its-debt